# How we can pass HashMap parameter in UrlEncodedFormEntity..?

Tags: java, android

How we can pass `HashMap` argument in `UrlEncodedFormEntity`? or how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean something like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> values = ....;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : values.entrySet()) {
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters);
```

**Edit** #2:

If your `HashMap` holds arbitrary values remember to do this instead:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = ....; // Your map goes here
ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Object value = entry.getValue();
    if (value instanceof Collection) {
        Collection<?> values = (Collection<?>) value;
        for (Object v : values) {
            // This will add a parameter for each value in the Collection/List
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), v == null ? null : String.valueOf(v)));
        }
    } else {
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), value == null ? null : String.valueOf(value));
    }
}
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters);
```

Comment: You should declare parameters as a `java.util.List`

Comment: Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  map.put(PARAM_USERNAME, username);
  map.put(PARAM_PASSWORD, password);
  map.put(PARAM_MODEL, "City");
  map.put(PARAM_ACTION, "add");
  map.put("city", city); How we can do this...?

Comment: map.put("city", city); this association contain another array list...whenever we send data it to server it make a string ...is there any way to send data without convert to string ...?

Comment: @singh, don't put code on a comment section, rather update your question.

Comment: Thanks,Actually i have map eg. Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  map.put(PARAM_USERNAME, username);
  map.put(PARAM_PASSWORD, password);
  map.put(PARAM_MODEL, "City");
  map.put(PARAM_ACTION, "add");
  map.put("City", city); and city type is final ArrayList<NameValuePair> city = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); when ever i encoded using UrlEncodedFormEntity this is not encoding proper... i want the output in this form Array(
    [action] => add
    [City] => Array(
[name] => Added from Chandiagrh
[state_id] => 4f8d4b37-2bec-405b-927a-16eafa739a52
)

)

Comment: You should really listen to @TheEliteGentleman & update your question instead - code pasted into comments looks like the left-overs from a night of heavy drinking.